# Flutter: Is it somehow possible to create App Widgets (Android) and Today Extensions (iOS)?

Tags: dart, android-widget, flutter, today-extension

I took a look at flutter for building a mobile app. Is it possible to create `Widgets` (not flutter-widgets, but `App Widgets` (Android) and `Today Extensions` (iOS)) in a flutter app? I guess it can't be done with dart, but is there a way of implementing them native in Java/Swift and include them in the flutter-app?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't know if app widgets could be built in flutter or not, but the opposite is definitely possible.

Comment: What do you mean by 'the opposite'? Including flutter in a native iOS/Android project?

Comment: I meant write app widgets natively and use them with flutter

Comment: @HemanthRaj are you sure? Widget are created with Skia. How can you use native widget? I think you can create your set of graphic widget via Skia...

Comment: I meant, create your home screen widgets natively and You can have application UI with flutter widgets

Comment: @hendra Yes, you can include flutter view to IOS/Android project.

Comment: @HemanthRaj Thanks! Just to make things clear: I'm talking about Home Screen Widgets, not Flutter Widgets :D Can you give me an entry point (link to documentation, blog post, example project) where a native homescreen-widget has been included into a flutter app?

Comment: @hendra I just answered your question. Do accept if it was what you were looking for.

Comment: It should be possible to implement communication between Android widget and the Flutter component, but there seems to be a bug. Please compare https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53940400/invoke-flutter-dart-code-from-native-android-home-screen-widget

Answer (score 50, accepted):

There is no guide or docs showing how to implement a App Widget for a flutter app. It is definitely possible to implement a app widget with native code. Just create a flutter project and open the android part with android studio, just implement your home screen widget, it'll work like a charm.

I just wrote a simple app widget for a flutter app that takes you to `https://flutter.io` link when tapped. [Here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Mhm1K8-Fh451vAEryK05RG54Iwp2ETp6) is the simple app created with flutter and a app widget added with native code. Install it and look for `home_widget_example` on Home Screen Widgets.

[image: Gif image]

If you wanted to look into the source code, and build app from source. [Here](https://github.com/hemanthrajv/flutter_home_screen_widget_example) it is.

Comment: Any idea to pass data to the widget button from flutter app. I need to call an API from the widget button.

Comment: Your implementation is Android-only. Flutter is a cross-platform framework

Comment: I just wanted to show the proof of concept of having native Android Widgets with flutter. Will try to add an example for IOS too. Or if you could please do, PRs are welcome :). Thanks @IhorKlimov.

Comment: You're using Android views to render the widget. Is it possible to render the widget using flutter?

Comment: AFAIK no, you cannot.