# How can I update an Android widget from Flutter while android:updatePeriodMillis="0"?

Tags: android, flutter, kotlin, android-widget

I'm very new here. I'm slowly getting the hang of Flutter but a complete novice at Kotlin/Java integration. I'm trying to make a Flutter app where some data is updated at irregular occasions within Flutter istelf and then displayed on a home screen widget.

I don't want to update the Android widget regularly because there will likely not be anything to change each day, but only occasionally. While looking for ways to actually make the widget, I found this [really helpful answer from bnxm](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61428629/14499364) and a good [implementation on Github from timobaehr](https://github.com/timobaehr/flutter-demo-android-widget).

Taking that as an example to work through, what if I wanted to update the "result" shown on the home screen widget whenever a button in the app was pressed (or a background service is run), rather than at a set interval? Timobaehr uses the default Flutter counting app in his demo, so what could I do with this code that is run when a button is pressed?

Here is the update function in main.dart:

```
void onWidgetUpdate() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  const MethodChannel channel = MethodChannel('com.example.app/widget');

  channel.setMethodCallHandler(
    (call) async {
      final id = call.arguments;

      print('on Dart ${call.method}!');

      return {
        'id': id,
        // Some data of type int - this is what I want to update
        'value': counter,
      };
    },
  );
}
```

Then below is the place in the code where the value gets updated, based on the default Flutter starting application. I've also moved `int counter = 0;` to the top of the dart file so it can be used everwhere.

```
void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      
      counter++;
      
    });

// How can I update the home screen widget from here?
// For example, send the new value of 'counter' to 'value' in the update function
// so that the new value is displayed on the home screen widget

  }
```

Is it as simple as adding something in here or will it require a change in the Kotlin code somewhere else? Thanks for your help.

Edit: I should have said, calling onWidgetUpdate() from the increment function doesn't change the widget at all, so I assume there must be something else that needs to happen, maybe in the background Kotlin code or with MethodChannels, which I am not familiar with.

If you want to run it yourself to test, I cloned from [timobaehr's Github project](https://github.com/timobaehr/flutter-demo-android-widget) and just changed the 'value' to come from 'counter' and be an int instead of a double.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, I think I got it. Posting it here in case it helps anyone else.

It was something that had to be changed in Kotlin, as I suspected. So a bit of extra learning for me! If you're following along with [timobaehr's project on Github](https://github.com/timobaehr/flutter-demo-android-widget) you can try making changes like this:

I wrote a new method called "updateFromFlutter" and added it to MainActivity.kt:

```
when (call.method) {
            "initialize" -> {
                if (call.arguments == null) return
                WidgetHelper.setHandle(this, call.arguments as Long)
            }
            "updateFromFlutter" -> {
                val views = RemoteViews(context.packageName, R.layout.widget_layout).apply {
                    setTextViewText(R.id.text, call.argument("text"))
                }

                val id: Int = call.argument("id")!!

                val manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this)
                manager.updateAppWidget(id, views)
            }
        }
```

Rememering to import these at the top of MainActivity.kt:

```
import android.widget.RemoteViews
import com.example.flutter_app_android_widget.R
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager
```

and called this from main.dart after updating the counter value:

```
const MethodChannel platform = MethodChannel('com.example.flutter_app_android_widget/widget');
platform.invokeMethod("updateFromFlutter", {
    "text": counter.toString(),
    "id": //get the integer from Shared Preferences - up to you how you do this
          //or feel free to suggest a better way of keeping track of the widget id
  });
```

Then you should be able to update the home screen widget on demand by pressing the button in your Flutter app.