# How to Create Homescreen widgets for flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i wondering how can Create like this Home Screen Shortcuts for my app in flutter
[image]

Answer (score 1):

App Widget example repo is here https://github.com/hemanthrajv/flutter_home_screen_widget_example

please reference detail [Flutter: Is it somehow possible to create App Widgets (Android) and Today Extensions (iOS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870740/flutter-is-it-somehow-possible-to-create-app-widgets-android-and-today-extens)

Author do it with Android Native Code 
and author follow this document to create native part https://medium.com/android-bits/android-widgets-ad3d166458d3

In example, author create a "url link" call tape it 
When user click "tape it", it will open url