# Screen widget with flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Can you make a screen widget with flutter? Is there a resource to learn, if any?

[image: For example]

Comment: Checkout this answer, looks like what you're trying to do: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47870740/flutter-is-it-somehow-possible-to-create-app-widgets-android-and-today-extens The only issue is that this solution only works on Android for now apparently.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by using a bottom tab navigations and google api for calling the current weather and corresponding data.