# how can I build Widgets using flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

[View screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5msVK.jpg)

I need to build this kind of widget to my flutter application.The widget should be can bring across the screen. is its possible? Then How can I do that?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: what you want to build ?

Comment: This one- https://i.stack.imgur.com/5msVK.jpg

Comment: okay, i post widgets code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47504574/is-it-possible-to-build-android-widgets-in-flutter

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Flutter can't create this type of widget (widget that you can add on your Home Screen) because Flutter uses his own custom rendering engine.

Answer (score -1):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

    void main() {
        runApp(MyApp());
    }

    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(“First Widgets")),
        body: myWidget(),
        ),  
        );
      }
    }

    Widget myWidget() {
      return Text(
        "Hello, World!",
      );
    }
}
```