# Class not found error for a custom Android widget in a Flutter project

Tags: android, flutter, widget, receiver

I'm a beginner in Flutter, and I'm attempting to create a custom Android widget within a Flutter project. I'm encountering an error "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.flutter_ure.ClockWidget" when I try to select my widget. Here's what I've already checked and done:

1. I have created a class **ClockWidget** that extends **AppWidgetProvider**. The class is located at **android/app/src/main/java/com/example/flutter_ure/ClockWidget.java**.
2. I have defined the receiver in my **AndroidManifest.xml** file as follows:

```
<receiver
    android:name="com.example.flutter_ure.ClockWidget"
    android:label="Clock"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/widget_clock" />
</receiver>
```

3. I have ensured that the package specified in my **AndroidManifest.xml** matches that in my Flutter project (**com.example.flutter_ure**).
4. The ClockWidget.java file includes the correct import for the R class:

```
import com.example.flutter_ure.R;
```

However, the error persists, and I'm unable to make my custom widget work. What am I doing wrong? How can I resolve this issue?

I would appreciate any help or advice to resolve this error. Thank you in advance.

-- Edit:
added a github repository for anyone who wants to play with it: https://github.com/motumboe/flutter_ure

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to build android widgets in flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47504574/is-it-possible-to-build-android-widgets-in-flutter)

Comment: The link provided is from six years ago, and perhaps things have changed since then. I've managed to add a widget to the home screen of my smartphone (as in widget_clock.xml, I get a 'Hello World' text in yellow). However, when I attempt to update it, I encounter the mentioned error. The widget, however, remains, displaying the original 'Hello World' text.

Comment: Wait, if you managed to make a custom android widget in Flutter that works, then what did you change so that it is broken now?

Comment: this was not a two step operation: refering to this project, https://github.com/motumboe/flutter_ure , I'm able to place a widget on the home screen (with the default text as defined in widget_clock.xml, "Hello World :-)" ), but I'm not able to update it each second (I get the aforementioned error). I'm not even able to remove the update call to avoid the error

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/appwidgets), **the name of the receiver should be the name of your widget class, and not the package to the class**.

For example,

```
<receiver android:name="ExampleAppWidgetProvider"
                 android:exported="false">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
               android:resource="@xml/example_appwidget_info" />
</receiver>
```

So, in your case, it would look like this:

```
<receiver
    android:name="ClockWidget"
    android:label="Clock"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
        android:resource="@xml/widget_clock" />
</receiver>
```

Comment: Hi Tomer, thank you very much for your reply! I have edited android\app\src\main\AndroidManifest.xml as suggest, but I still get 
```E/AndroidRuntime(32248): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.flutter_ure.ClockWidget: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.flutter_ure.ClockWidget" on path (...)```
Sorry but I don't know where to look

Comment: @MarcoLazzaroni - could you please update your question with the updated manifest file? Also could you share the class itself?

Comment: added a github repository for anyone who wants to play with it:
https://github.com/motumboe/flutter_ure